# Magento 2.2.5: "The itemprop attribute was specified, but the element is not a property of any item"

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

Does anyone have any idea what I need to add in order to solve the issues for the following piece of code?

```html
<div class="product-info-main">
    <div class="product attribute overview">
        <div class="value" itemprop="description">
            KISS KISS BANG BANG
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-info-price">
        <div class="page-title-wrapper product">
            <h1 class="page-title"><span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper" itemprop="name">FAUX FUR TEDDY COAT</span></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="price-box price-final_price" data-price-box="product-id-9586" data-product-id="9586" data-role="priceBox">
            <span class="normal-price"><span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"><span class="price-wrapper" data-price-amount="350" data-price-type="finalPrice" id="product-price-9586"><span class="price">€350.00</span></span></span></span>
            <meta content="350" itemprop="price">
            <meta content="EUR" itemprop="priceCurrency">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The errors are for the following pieces of code:

```html
<div class="value" itemprop="description">KISS K...

<span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper" itemprop="name">...

<span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">...

<meta itemprop="price" content="350" />...    

<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR" />...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your price and priceCurrency are out of scope of the Offer. The working code would be probably:

```
<div class="product-info-main">
    <div class="product attribute overview">
        <div class="value" itemprop="description">
            KISS KISS BANG BANG
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-info-price">
        <div class="page-title-wrapper product">
            <h1 class="page-title"><span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper" itemprop="name">FAUX FUR TEDDY COAT</span></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="price-box price-final_price" data-price-box="product-id-9586" data-product-id="9586" data-role="priceBox">
            <span class="normal-price"><span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"><span class="price-wrapper" data-price-amount="350" data-price-type="finalPrice" id="product-price-9586"><span class="price">€350.00</span>
                        <meta content="350" itemprop="price">
            <meta content="EUR" itemprop="priceCurrency">
            </span></span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Evgeniy; i've adjusted it like described in your code, but this does not help; still the same error :(

Comment: then you do something wrong. look at the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Removing everything which is not relevant for Microdata, you have:

```html
<div itemprop="description">KISS KISS BANG BANG</div>

<span itemprop="name">FAUX FUR TEDDY COAT</span>

<span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"></span>

<meta content="350" itemprop="price">
<meta content="EUR" itemprop="priceCurrency">
```

Unless you have a parent Microdata item (with `itemscope` and possibly `itemtype`) not shown in your snippet, none of your `itemprop` attributes is associated with an item, which is invalid.

I assume your data is about a `Product`, so it should be something like this:

```
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">

  <p itemprop="description">KISS KISS BANG BANG</p>

  <h2 itemprop="name">FAUX FUR TEDDY COAT</h2>

  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <meta content="350" itemprop="price">
    <meta content="EUR" itemprop="priceCurrency">
  </div>

</article>
```

Comment: `Removing everything which is not relevant for Microdata` - you can't just hack Magento, it stops working or at least breaks the layout. The better idea would be to move into JSON-LD direction.

Comment: @Evgeniy: It’s not meant to be changed in the Magento site. I only removed it to point out which parts are relevant for Microdata. All the `span`/`div` elements with `class` attributes can be added/removed as desired.